# NUnit CollectionConstraints exceptions

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-2.5

I'm using NUnit 2.5.6.10205 in a .NET 3.5 C# app. I'm using NUnit's [Collection Constraint](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5.6) to assert if an IEnumerable is sorted by a paramter.

It doesn't seem to be working for me, as I'm getting an exception indicating that my actual value isn't an IEnumreable. allEntities is a `List<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>` . I believe that NUnit is looking for an `IEnumerable`, not an `IEnumerable<T>`, but `IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable`. Is this an issue of co / contra variance?

```
Assert.That(allEntities, Is.All.Ordered.By("CreationDate"));
```

.

```
System.ArgumentException : The actual value must be an IEnumerable
Parameter name: actual
```

Also, is there some way I can express the sort property using a Lambda? Using a literal string for the property makes it brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the `All`, try:

```
Assert.That(allEntities, Is.Ordered.By("CreationDate"));
```

Comment: I'll give you the check so it doesn't look like I put up a question just to answer it myself :)

Comment: Thx, but you were faster with 15 sec :). +1 to your more complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the All contstraint, but that is used to make assertions on each item in the list, i.e.

```
// checks that for each T in myList, that it is greater than 5
Assert.That(myList, Is.All.GreaterThan(5));
```

From [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5.6): "Applies a constraint to each item in a collection, succeeding only if all of them succeed."

I want to test a property of the list itself, so I want:

```
// checks that the list itself is ordered by the property CreationDate
Assert.That(allEntities, Is.Ordered.By("CreationDate"));
```

Hopefully someone else will find this question / answer useful in the future.